# Why did cross product only exist for three and seven dimensions?

Tags: vectors, mathematics, spacetime-dimensions, complex-numbers

According to [this wikipage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-dimensional_cross_product#Relation_to_the_octonions),

> The cross product only exists in three and seven dimensions as one can always define a multiplication on a space of one higher dimension as above, and this space can be shown to be a normed division algebra.

There was an answer on math.stackexchange.com by [riemannium](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/462895/603316) and [another related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706011/why-is-cross-product-only-defined-in-3-and-7-dimensions), where riemannium mentioned that: "A 2-fold cross vector exists in dimension 3 and 7. Therefore, the "bilinear" cross product can only exists with two factors in 3D and 7D."

To elaborate in the terms of physics, besides the mathematical reasons stated above, was there any physical/geometrical reasoning behind this statement? Further, does it have any implications to the structure of space?

Comment: This is purely a mathematical problem. Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: This question is probably more suitable for the Mathematics Stack Exchange, but see http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/octonions/node14.html

Comment: @Qmechanic Mathematics answered it in algebra as mentioned in the post, but it didn't answer how it apply to physics, i.e. with established theory such as GR and high dimensional physics. There's too many assumptions in physics and mathematicians might not like it.

Comment: @ShoutOutAndCalculate To clarify, are you asking if there is a physical reason why a cross product-like structure can only be defined for vector spaces of either 3 or 7 dimensions?

Comment: @J.Murray that's only one part, but I doubt if there's any good answer since to the bottom it got to do with the norm, which was boring. but it might had some implications, i.e. to build a more visualized understanding in 8 dimension with octonions etc.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer is purely mathematical. And any prediction about spacetime would be highly speculative.