# What happened to positive energy theorem for $n\geq 8$?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, mathematical-physics

I was flipping through Geometric Relativity by Dan A. Lee where on chapter $8$ the book proved spacetime positive energy theorem for $3\leq n <8$.

What happened to positive energy theorem  for $n\geq 8$? Why it even matter to $n$ for this theorem, and that $n=8$ being a cut off?

(It kind of troubled a bit since yesterday I had a somewhat related question about cross product as well: [Why did cross product only exist for three and seven dimensions?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/557642/why-did-cross-product-only-exist-for-three-and-seven-dimensions)  .
It seemed that "nice things" broke off at $n=8$ )

Comment: See the following paper: https://lhhuang.math.uconn.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/1744/2019/04/spacetimePMT_JEMS.pdf. " In dimensions higher than 7, a complication arises in the Schoen-Yau argument due to possible singularities of minimal hypersurfaces"